# Navigation issue with Sidebar on macOS (SwiftUI)

Tags: macos, swiftui, xcode12

I do have an app with a sidebar where I place my main navigation. When I navigate from the sidebar my DetailView is shown next to the sidebar as it should. But when I want to navigate from my MainView to a DetailView it's not working. The view is only shown as an overlay.

Is there any way I can navigate around my main window from the sidebar and from the main view itself?

```
import SwiftUI
@main
struct NavigationTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
                MainView()
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: DetailView(),
                label: {
                    Text("DetailView")
                })
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
}
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: DetailView(),
            label: {
                Text("Navigate") /* Navigation does not work properly here*/
            })
            .frame(width: 1280, height: 720)
    }
}
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("DetailView")
            .frame(width: 1280, height: 720)
    }
}
```